# Can not read the tables of excel sheets in R

Tags: r

Warning message:
In read.table("my_data.xls", header = T, sep = ";") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'my_data.xls'

```
> read.table("my_data.xls", header = T, sep = ";")
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using this package ?

Comment: read.table wasn't designed to read excel files. Use readxl, xlsx or any other package for that exact purpose

Comment: I have imported the dataset in R and now i want to access its values what should i do?

Comment: rows <- read.table("my_data", sep = ",", header = T) this too i have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use the readxl package. Not sure about the use of ";" as separator.

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel( "my_data.xls", col_names = TRUE )
```

Comment: But in this way i can not apply eclat algorithm code.

Comment: That's a separate question.